# What's the difference between the Spektrum DX6 and DX6e?

Tags: transmitter, spektrum

Besides 90 bucks :-)

Looking through the specifications, they're both DSM2/DSMX radios with more model memories than you can use, 6 channels, wireless trainer, telemetry, 7 aircraft wing mixing types and 6 tail types.

The only differences I can see is 4 vs 5 programmable mixes, and 2 vs 7 helicopter swashplate types.

Is there a less-obvious feature that's missing, that would mean an average beginner would need to upgrade from one to the other? (and, yes, I know Flysky and Jumper offer great value, I'm just curious about how Spektrum differentiate these two transmitters.)

Links to Spektrum's website for comparison: [DX6e](https://www.spektrumrc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdId=SPM6650) [DX6](https://www.spektrumrc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdId=SPM6755)

Answer (score 3):

I found [this comparison chart](https://www.spektrumrc.com/Content/Media/PDF/SPM_Transmitter_Comparison.pdf) in an [rcgroups thread](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2757247-New-dx6e-vs-new-dx6). The DX6e and DX6 (G3 in this case) are very similar, but the biggest differences that I could find is that the DX6e doesn't have voice alerts and that it doesn't support wired trainer, which will make it harder to use with for example a simulator on a PC. The DX6e also supports mode 5, where the throttle centers with a spring.

I see no compelling reason to upgrade from one to the other. If you want to use it with a simulator (which you probably want, at least as a beginner) it is cheaper to just buy a wireless adapter to be able to connect the transmitter to the PC via the wireless trainer link.

Comment: I wonder if it could work with a simulator via a USB port? I can see voice alerts being considered a 'high-end' feature, but easy simulator connectivity is something beginners really need.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm not sure that either of the transmitters actually has a USB connection. All the information I could find online talks about a wireless adapter or an adapter cable that connects to the trainer port. If they do have USB, it is would be very weird if it didn't support using it as game controller that way.

Answer (score 1):

I owned both, the 6E used AA batteries until you upgrade. Very similar otherwise, the 6E is "economy".

Spektrum had to be dropped because the RX and protocol is not as compatible as other units.  I purchased 4 different Spektrum TRX and close to 20 different RX and verifiably concluded that the RX configuration was to blame, specifically interference from carbon fiber on the frames.  Many walk of shame because of Spektrum, luckily no one was hurt, but I do consider Spektrum data protocols o be a liability.

Other hits against Spektrum, because it is quite important:

- They are well known for stealing clients from independent hobby shops (several reports via Horizon Hobby)
- No repair manuals! This is VERY VERY BAD!
- Repair only by their service center (part of how they steal clients from small shops)
- The firmware has bugs. For example - I totally reverse engineered and hacked a 6e only to find out that travel of the potentiometers beyond certain values would reset the position to 0/middle.
- Telemetry is optional and expensive

The technology used by Spektrum is plane-centric.  Once I switched to FRSky, a drone aware engineering company, I was shocked when everything worked and my performance on data (TRX/RX) more than tripled.

If you are looking for an upgrade do consider FrSky/Taranis. I met that team and spent some time with them - they are in it to win it. Spektrum is part of a large conglomerate that is tied up with a lot of dirty stuff.  In fact, they are owned by Horizon Hobby.

Personally, I have always considered Futaba to be the best choice for heli, I may be wrong as I am more invested in FPV than anything right now.